# Change image of Submit button

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I wanted to Change the submit button of my form.I manage to do it and Its quite easy however the code breaks. When i fixed the code. The submit button changes back to its default image and it said submit query which i did not initialize. I have not figured out how to fix it since then. Which is weird.

```
<?Php
    echo "<div style='text-align:right'>
       <form action='upd2.php' method='POST'>
       <Table border='0' align='right'>
       <tr>
        <td ><font size='-3'>ID Search</font></td>
        <td rowspan =2><input name='image' type='image' id='SUBMIT' src='images/_Images_buttons_search_button.jpg'></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><input name='ID_NO' type='text' id='ID_NO'></td>
       </tr>
       </table><br>
       </FORM> </div>";
?>
```

I pass it on to this

```
<?php
    print "<H2>Update User Info</H2>";

    $ID_NO   = clean($_POST['ID_NO']);
 $_SESSION["ID_NO"] = $ID_NO;
     if (isset($_POST['image'])) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE ID_NO = '$ID_NO'");
        if(!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
            print "<BR><BR>There is no such User with a User Number of $ID_NO <BR><A HREF ='UpdateUser.php'>Go Back</A>";
     exit();
        }
        else {
            $row_array = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
?>
```

however, it does not work(the variable wasnt able to get it). I should have change "image" with "SUBMIT". But if I do that, then the image would be in default.

so in short

type='SUBMIT' -> i get to make the code work but default picture.

type='image' -> i get the nice image but the code wont work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just set the background image of the button using css.

```
<input type="submit" style="background-image: url(bgb.png);" />
```

(Better to use separate style sheet off course)